# File access permissions: Running app under PM2 gives EACCES denied for a file my app needs

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, node.js

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 environment.

I have a NodeJS app that is running a webserver and needs access to the certificates to enable HTTPS.
When I run the app under pm2 (user: brad), I receive a *EACCES: permission denied, open 'file url here'*
When I run the app using node (cmd: node .), I don't get this error and the app starts successfully.

Both PM2 and Node are ran under the same user (brad).
The file I am accessing is protected (letsencrypt private key for a certificate), so that the group has read access (the user, brad, is a member of this group, group is called 'ssl'). chmod 740 is applied to the file (privkey1.pem), and I am referencing the symlink file in the NodeJS app, which the permissions are open for all users to read.

Unsure why pm2 has such difficulties when both pm2 and node are ran under the same user.
What am I missing?
Is it possible pm2 is actually running under another user?
I ran *ps aux | grep pm2* as well as *ps aux | grep node* and both are showing to be ran under user 'brad'